# GA4 Admin API for .Net not returning MeasurementUnit for CustomMetrics. Always null

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm using the .Net library for the GA4 admin API. When I request CustomMetrics the MeasurementUnit in the response is always null.

Am I missing something?

```
var service = new GoogleAnalyticsAdminService(...);    
var metricsList = service.Properties.CustomMetrics.List("properties/1234567890");
var metricsResponse = await metricsList.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
foreach(var customMetric in metricsResponse.CustomMetrics) {
    Debug.WriteLine($"{customMetric.DisplayName}.MeasurementUnit={customMetric.MeasurementUnit ?? "(null)"}"); // Always null
}
```

I've also noticed that the patch method does not accept measurement_unit in the UpdateMask.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I've added a bit more. Not sure what else I can add that is of value. I can't provide my oauth credentials to create the service or my real parent name for the metric. Basically the request works with all data but the MeasurementUnit